# Faster version of length(find()) for selecting elements from some range from vectors (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have 1Xn cell array  of values. and I want to count values that are in given range in matlab. 
I implemented it as follows :

```
count1 = length(find(h{1}<ti & h{1}>ti-INT));
```

h is my cell array and I want the count of values between ti and ti-INT.

This implementation give correct result, but it is very slow. 
Is there any faster function available for the specified operation ?

Comment: For faster calculations use matrices, not cells

Comment: as this is 1Xn cell array, i can do that. can you please provide conversion and operation in the answer ? @Adriaan

Comment: Best would be to create your data as a matrix, not a cell array. What you can do now, however, is using `cell2mat`, which will make a `1 x n` matrix out of your cells, then use one of the methods already mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sum the occurrence flags:

```
 count1 = sum(h{1}<ti & h{1}>ti-INT);
```

I know that I will upset the Gods of MATLAB for using `tic` and `toc` for code timig, but:

```
x = rand(10^7,1);
tic; sum(x>0.5); toc;
tic; nnz(x>0.5); toc;
tic; length(find(x>0.5)); toc;
```

shows on several runs that `sum()` is twice as fast as `nnz()`, and 3 times faster than `length(find())`, e.g.:

```
Elapsed time is 0.049855 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.120931 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.162025 seconds.
```

This is on my R2012a running on a Windows machine with i5 + 3Gb RAM.

*Later edit:*

For counting the elements from the entire cell array, one may use:

```
count_all = sum(cellfun(@(x) sum(x<ti & x>ti-INT), h));
```

Comment: This will sum values of h or find count ??

Comment: @KrunalParmar Did you try it? To illustrate the idea, think of how you'd solve the following problem: find the number of ones in the array `[1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]` knowing that there are only ones and zeros.

Comment: Yes, tried that. but it is as slow as find. not much difference in speed.

Comment: @KrunalParmar I guess that's the fastest that it gets with the information that you provided. 0) Is this operation done in a loop? 1) What numeric type is `h{1}`? 2) What size is `h{1}`. 3) What numeric types are `ti` and `INT`? 4) How did you benckmarked this as "slow"? 5) What would qualify as "fast"?

Comment: Instead of `sum` use `nnz`. The result is the same for binary arrays but conceptually it's better to use nnz. nzz counts the number of non-zero elements (which is what we want). In the other hans sum adds all the values of a vector. Even if results are the same nzz is conceptually better.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Interesting. You should place your suggestion as a separate answer.

Comment: I ran the same test and `nnz` and `sum` take almost the same time. Generating the random numbers every time changes the elapsed time, sometimes `nnz` is faster and sometimes `sum` is faster but we are talking about very small percentages

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I guess that depends on the MATLAB version too. But usually I trust `sum` being the most optimized function, because is one of the most basic and most used.

Comment: [Much better timing code](https://gist.github.com/sco1/457805b1d7c213233ee21563dc2a31eb)

Comment: @excaza Thanks for the suggestion. Gonna check it when I get home, cannot access the site from work.

Comment: Deleted my answer as it seems to be useless and not provide any new information to the question. So don't use `nnz` since it takes double the time of `sum`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki That depends, I would say. Of course the intention of `nnz` is more transparent than the `sum` of logical's. But when needed to squeeze the last bit of performance for a "write-once-and-throw-away", sometimes obscurity is acceptable. I believe that the performance difference is caused by the fact that `nnz` actually compares each element to zero before incrementing the counter, while `sum` blindly sums ones. Moreover, my old version might lose supplemental time to convert the logical to double before performing the comparison. But, of course, this is speculation...